# How do I interpret this QQ plot?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, qq-plot

I am calculating a multiple regression with a sample of 128 and I was wondering, what distribution would best describe this residuals qq plot? It seems like a a Poisson-distribution to me, is it correct?

Should I then proceed with counting a Poisson-regression model to adress this violation of normal distribution?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need a QQ plot to decide on whether a Poisson distribution is appropriate - the properties of the data would tell you more.

Comment: Clearly the residuals do not have a Poisson distribution, because no Poisson variable can have negative values.